# Airtel 3G dongle 9(Huawei E303H) is not supporting in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

I have problem with airtel dongle, I use Airtel 3G dongle 9(Huawei E303H) which is not supporting in windows 8.1 when is insert the dongle am unable to download the airtel software itself. I dont have good knowledge about computer. If anybody has a driver link from Huawei, please share me so please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Can you confirm if dongle drivers are loaded in your device manager.  You can check it in right click on "this computer"  => properties  => Device manager.

Comment: If it's present uninstall them.

Answer (score 1):

To connect your dongle, first download extract and install [Mobile Partner](http://download-c.huawei.com/download/downloadCenter?downloadId=18474&siteCode=worldwide).

Then proceed to settings and click create account.

The parameters are as follows:

- Access Point (APN)/Home Page = Airtel or airtellive
- IP Settings = 10.200.184.86
- Port Number = 8080
- Dial Up Number = *99#
- User Name = BLANK
- Password = BLANK

If you cannot set up with these instructions, please comment on what went wrong.

Comment: @Aravind Did my answer work? If it did, lease check the transparent tick to the left of my answer, to mark it answered. If it did not, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following when I faced thee same issue:

- Connect dongle to your old OS / any Windows 7 machine. Go to My Computer, click on the dongle icon, to go inside.
- Select All and Copy.
- Paste the contents to removable storage device (around 40 MB).
- Connect the removable storage device and Dongle to your Windows 8 OS.
- Open the folder and click on Autorun.
- Your drivers + app will be installed.
- You may need to remove and reconnect the dongle before use.

Hope it help, cheers.